# How to launch device's notification settings for my Android app from a PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I would like to launch the phone's notification settings for my Android app(Oreo version) from a PreferenceScreen.
I am using below in preferences.xml file. However, it does not work. Does anyone have an idea?

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/Notification">
    <intent android:action="android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS"
            android:data="package:com.my_app_package_name" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Android 5-7:
    You have to call start activity from code (programmatically) because there is no way to determine uid of the app in Layout file

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS");
intent.putExtra("app_package", getPackageName());
intent.putExtra("app_uid", getApplicationInfo().uid);
```

For Android O up:

```
<intent android:action="android.settings.APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS">
    <extra android:name="android.provider.extra.APP_PACKAGE" android:value="your app package name" />    
</intent>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, could you please mark my answer as "accepted". I'm really appreciate it. Thank you.